# Can't get multiple PHP versions to work (PHP7.4-FPM and PHP8.2-FPM)

Tags: 22.04, apache2, php, virtualhost, php-fpm

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with Apache2. I can't get both PHP versions to work. When I access a site I have configured with PHP 7.4, only shows 8.2. I have searched and tried things but I can't get it to work.

I have php7.4-fpm and php8.2-fpm services working.

In teste.conf I have it already enabled with `sudo a2ensite teste`

`teste.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
     ServerAdmin admin@teste
     ServerName teste.local
     DocumentRoot /var/www/teste

     <Directory /var/www/teste>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
   <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
   </If>
</FilesMatch>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teste_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teste_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and in `webtransito.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
     ServerAdmin admin@webtransito
     ServerName webtransito.local
     DocumentRoot /var/www/webtransito
     DirectoryIndex info.php

     <Directory /var/www/webtransito>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
   <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
   </If>
</FilesMatch>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/webtransito_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/webtransito_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2ctl -M`:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

`ps -A | grep php`:

```
  91080 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.4
  97203 ?        00:00:01 php-fpm7.4
  98903 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.4
  98904 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.4
 112019 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm8.2
 112020 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm8.2
 112021 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm8.2
```

Thanks in advance.
If more files are needed I can share them.

Comment: Can you share the configuration files of the sites you've configured?

Comment: Thanks i have edited the post

Comment: Usually Apache use mod_php rather than php-fpm to provide it's version of PHP, and IIRC you can only have one version of mod_php installed.  You can configure Apache to use PHP-FPM, some useful pointers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server

Comment: @PedroPauloCampanhaFilho your configs look OK. Can you edit your answer again and add the results of these commands: `apache2ctl -M` and `ps -A | grep php`

Comment: These look OK too. How are you checking your php version?

Comment: Im using a phpinfo file, but it only shows PHP Version 8.2.11

Comment: Are you checking it from the console or from the browser?

Comment: checking from the browser

Comment: Strange. I have a machine with settings very similar to yours. What do you have in `/var/www/teste`? How do you access the site, from `http://teste.local` I suppose?

Comment: ok, i managed it to work, when i access it http://teste.local:9090/info.php it works PHP 7.4 but when i access http://localhost:9090/teste/info.php it shows PHP 8.2

Comment: @PedroPauloCampanhaFilho I just updated my answer with instructions how to change the default PHP version for the Apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have said to me, your configuration works exactly as it should. Your problem is not understanding how virtual hosts work.

- When you open `http://teste.local:9090/info.php`, it uses your `teste.conf`.
- When you open `http://localhost:9090/teste/info.php`, it uses your default Apache config, probably `000-default.conf`.

You can disable `php8.2` and replace the default PHP version for the Apache server with `php7.4-fpm` by doing this:

```
sudo a2dismod php8.2
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork

sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm

sudo service apache2 restart
```